# Mysql 10 min avergage 1to10 min

Tags: mysql, average

I need to calculate 10 minute average of my MySql table. But the default average it's not what I want. I've a code for "default" average:

```
SELECT Date, convert((min(Time) DIV 1000)*1000,time) as Time, ROUND(AVG(Value),2) FROM RawData
    GROUP BY Date, Time DIV 1000
```

How can I calculate average like this:
http://prntscr.com/8k4slp

And one more thing... I need to prevent the average calculation of incomplete intervals. How can I do this?

Comment: Please put the relevant information about what you want to do in the question.  A remote link is helpful for additional information and clarification, but it shouldn't be the basis for the question.